# Cannot format device /dev/sda4 which is still in use

Tags: centos, mount, partition, encryption, luks

When I try to LUKS encrypt a partition on a CentOS 7 server using the command `cryptsetup -y luksFormat /dev/sda4`, the attempt fails with the error `Cannot format device /dev/sda4 which is still in use.`  **How can I resolve this error and successfully LUKS encrypt the partition?**

Here is the terminal record:

```
[root@localhost ~]# df -h
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/dm-1        50G  1.1G   46G   3% /
devtmpfs        3.8G     0  3.8G   0% /dev
tmpfs           3.8G     0  3.8G   0% /dev/shm
tmpfs           3.8G  8.7M  3.8G   1% /run
tmpfs           3.8G     0  3.8G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/sda6       296G   65M  281G   1% /vpn
/dev/sda2       477M  110M  338M  25% /boot
/dev/sda1       200M  9.8M  191M   5% /boot/efi
/dev/sda3       596G   73M  565G   1% /home
/dev/sda7       296G   65M  281G   1% /test
/dev/sda5       296G   65M  281G   1% /public
/dev/sda4       296G   65M  281G   1% /data
[root@localhost ~]# cryptsetup -y luksFormat /dev/sda4

WARNING!
========
This will overwrite data on /dev/sda4 irrevocably.

Are you sure? (Type uppercase yes): YES
Enter passphrase: 
Verify passphrase: 
Cannot format device /dev/sda4 which is still in use.
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Is the goal to completely destroy everything on your current `/data` disk and create a new, entirely empty encrypted volume? Because that's what you're doing with this command. That's what the whole "WARNING: This will overwrite data on /dev/sda4 irrevocably" thing is about. You will lose all the current data, and start over with an empty block device.

More likely, what you want to do is take a data backup of `/data`, create the new volume, then restore the backup into the new, encrypted filesystem. You can use `tar` for this nicely:

```
cd /data
tar czvf /root/data_backup.tar.gz .
```

Then, and only then, do you write over the filesystem using `cryptsetup`. The way to get around your error is by unmounting first:

```
umount /data
cryptsetup -y luksFormat /dev/sda4
```

Then you can `luksOpen` the new /dev/sda4, then `mkfs` onto the encrypted mapping, `mount` the result, and finally cd into it and restore the existing data with `tar`.

If you are actually, 100% sure that you want to irrevocably destroy everything in the current `/data`, then skip the first step, and just jump down to `umount /data`.

Edit: If you're doing this at all it's possible that the current data is sensitive. If so, consider:

- `cryptsetup luksFormat` does *not* overwrite all existing data. It only overwrites the first few KiB. If the data is sensitive you will first want to overwrite all data on the partition, e.g. with `wipe`, see https://superuser.com/questions/831486/complete-wiping-of-hard-drive-shred-wipe-or-dd. If the partition is large and if there is not much data on the other partitions it will be faster to include all data in a backup on external storage, use the internal disk's "secure erase" feature to blank it in an instant, prepare `/data` with LUKS and restore your backup.
- To not contaminate `/root` with the sensitive data, write to a sufficiently large tmpfs, a smaller volume which you can secure-erase afterward or a new filesystem in an encrypted container, or pipe the `tar` output through `gpg` before writing the backup.
- `cryptsetup-reencrypt` can encrypt the data in-place. As the tool is not crash resistant, having a backup is still advisable.

An existing backup becomes the primary copy during the operation. For important data, a second backup should be made so that more than one copy exists at all times.

Comment: my volume is unmounted but I still get this error

Comment: @robertspierre Common reasons: systemd mounting /home again automatically, there is a bind mount of the same volume on another mount point, the volume is part of an md raid or a PV of LVM. What was it in your case (if you can remember 11 months later)?

Comment: @tomhunt why do we do `umount /data` and not `umount /dev/sda4`? Does it unmount all other sda* if we do `umount /data`?

Comment: @robinhoodjr `umount /dev/sda4` is equivalent to `umount /data` in this case, since `/dev/sda4` is the device mounted on `/data`. None of the other `/dev/sda*` are affected, nor do they matter for this question.